# Apple Watch - update glance on background

Tags: ios, background, apple-watch

I'm developing an AppleWatch app and I would like to know if it is possible to update the glance in background. When the user open the glance, I want to have the glance updated INMEDIATLY, and not wait until the glance receives the updated information from the service and presents it.

Currently Im using this functions to update the glance, but this will show the information updated not inmediatly.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context // This function can't spend too much time processing the data otherwise we will se a black background. Can't call the service here.
{
    //Configure the interface using the cached info. 
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
}


- (void)willActivate 
{
    //Configure the interface using the service
    [super willActivate];
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule background fetch in your iOS app and after that fetch, save data to shared group container. 
Then in awakeWithContext method of your glance controller you can fetch data from that shared group container. It should be fast enough.

Answer (score -1):

The very first time your glance appears, you can provide the user a generic welcome message in `init`. Then, in `willActivate` (or, I suppose, `awakeWithContext:`) populate your controls and kick off a timer to regularly grab updated content for the glance.

As Ivp suggested, you should store the updated data in a shared container. (Take a look at [NSUserDefaults:initWithSuiteName:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/initWithSuiteName:))

If you know your iPhone app will be launched before your glance is launched, you can skip the generic welcome message, and just rely on it to seed the data in the shared container.

Here's a sample of what I describe above, though it doesn't show the storage of the data in the shared container.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        if (isFirstLaunch) {
            self.displayInfo = [self createWelcomeInfo];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

    // refreshUI will check for new data, request more for next time,
    // and then configure the display labels with the new data.
    [self refreshUI]; 

    // Setup a timer to refresh the glance based on new trends provided by the phone app.
    // NOTE: This timer is never invalidated because didDeactivate seems to never be called.
    //       If, by chance, willActivate is called more than once, we may end up with multiple repeating timers.
    self.refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kTimeIntervalRefresh
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(refreshUI)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
}

- (void)refreshUI {
    if (! isFirstLaunch ) {
        if (self.nextDisplayInfo) {
            self.displayInfo = self.nextDisplayInfo;
        }

        // requestMoreInfo will populate self.nextDisplayInfo asynchronously,
        // so it's ready for the next time you are in refreshUI
        [self requestMoreInfo];
    }

    [self configureLabels:self.displayInfo];

    // Setup for when the user taps the glance
    [self updateUserActivity:@"com.example.AppName" userInfo:@{@"data": self.displayInfo} webpageURL:nil];    
}
```